# Relationship between cross product and outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, vector-spaces

Since inner products $(V)$ are generalisations of dot products $(\mathbb{R}^n),$ then are outer products $(V)$ also related to cross products $(\mathbb{R}^3)$ in some way?

A quick search reveals that they are—yet the outer product of two column vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^3$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, not another column vector. What is the connection?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_product.

Comment: Just found this, on the ambiguity of the term "outer product": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AOuter_product#Outer_product_vs_exterior_product

Comment: Hii ryang! I hope you are doing good. Just want to inform you that I'll no longer be available here. MSE is a little addictive for me and I think I've wasted a lot of time here in editing and reviewing. Also, I no longer need to do maths for my course. You are the only one whom I know here. You are really a nice person and I again thank you for all your help you provided on my questions.
You may notice a change in your reputation states "User was removed", apologies for that. And lastly, English is not my native language so please ignore any grammatical mistakes above. 
Good byee!! ;-)

Comment: @Yooo Good luck with your future endeavours!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is much more related to [exterior product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) which is in fact a far going generalization.

[Outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) is a matricial description of [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of two vectors.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So are outer products and exterior products related in some way then? In http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/clifford/theory/extendXProduct/index.htm , the author claims that "Inner product by a vector reduces the grade of a multivector. It is related to the dot product. **Outer product** by a vector increases the grade of a multivector. It **is related to the cross product**." and I've seen this claim elsewhere too. Are they mixing up their terminologies?

Comment: I think it is naming conventions ambiguity. In your reference outer product is exactly what I call exterioir product.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product states that "The interior product, named in opposition to the exterior product ... should not be confused with an inner product." So Inner is a generalisation of Dot. Exterior is a generalisation of Cross. Interior is in opposition to Exterior but shld not be confused with Inner. Can someone put these into a simple framework for me? For eg. how is Inner related to Interior then??

Comment: Interior product is degree descending operation. It looks like inner product, but this is just an _analogy_. Here is an example of how one can define interior product given some $x\in V$. You _define_ interioir product of vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ as exterior product of $x, x_1,\ldots, x_n$. Note that interioir product depends on the choice of vector $x$. Interioir products are closely related to annihilation operators on the Fock space in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks Norbert. Is this map fair? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/182024/21813

Answer (score 2):

In Geometric algebra, the cross-product of two vectors is the dual  (i.e. a vector in the orthogonal subspace) of the outer product of those vectors in $\mathbb{G}^3$ (so in a way you could say that the outer product generalizes the dot product, although the cross product is not an outer product). This is very well explained in [the great introduction series to Geometric Algebra by Alan Macdonald](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLvlxwbzkr7igd6bL7959WWE7XInCCevt).
The relation between the cross product and the outer product is mentioned in [Geometric Algebra 4 at min 6:20](https://youtu.be/C-3FdRgUhvY?t=379).

Now Geometric algebra is just Clifford algebra, with a different emphasis, so that these definitions are equivalent to the definitions in that algebra.

Answer (score -1):

The inner product creates a scalar and the outer a skew-symmetric matrix. If you sum like-terms of this matrix you get a vector which also results from the cross product computation.

Comment: What do you mean by `sum like-terms of this matrix`? How to sum?